# How to solve the issue in using Location services with Async in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, gps

In my windows phone application I'm getting the using current location using the following code

```
        private void GetCoordinate()
    {
        var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High)
        {
            MovementThreshold = 2
        };
        watcher.PositionChanged += this.watcher_PositionChanged;
        watcher.StatusChanged += this.watcher_StatusChanged;
        watcher.Start();
    }

    void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:
                MessageBox.Show("Current position not available!!");
                break;
            case GeoPositionStatus.NoData:
                MessageBox.Show("Current position not available!!");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        try
        {
            var pos = e.Position.Location;
            StaticData.currentCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(pos.Latitude, pos.Longitude);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

As shown above I am calling the `GetCoordinate` method in the page load event of the application page. By using that `GPS` coordinate values I was enabling or disabling some controls on the page. But here, the issue is page load code executing first and then we are getting the `Gps` coordinate values..

I need the `GPS` Coordinate values in `pageload`. please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall start the watcher in the page load, and once the GeoCoordinateWatcher collects the GeoCoordinate value it triggers PositionChanged event where in you shall code for enabling disabling the controls.

So now your code would look like this

```
  private void GetCoordinate()
    {
        var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High)
        {
            MovementThreshold = 2
        };
        watcher.PositionChanged += this.watcher_PositionChanged;
        watcher.StatusChanged += this.watcher_StatusChanged;
        watcher.Start();
    }

private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        try
        {
            var pos = e.Position.Location;
            if(position==required one)
             {
                //enable disable here  
             }
            StaticData.currentCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(pos.Latitude, pos.Longitude);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually i have a pivot control on my page. i need to show some of the items in the pivot control only for some GPS coordinates other wise i need show different items in the pivot control..If i use like this,initially there will be nothing to show on the page..please suggest

Comment: you cant get the geocoordinates till the position changed event donot gets fired hence This is the only possible way to solve the issue